# Adding time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I want to add time in SQL Server. I have a column called `checktime` in the database which is a `datetime` datatype. I want to add the time from the column `checktime`. How can I do this ??

I'm doing this calculation for calculating total hrs an employee has worked during a specified day.

My database look like this.. I want to add  the time from `checktime` where `checktype = 1` and `checktype = 2` and then subtract the results.
(checktype = 1 means check in and checktype = 2 means check out)

How can I do this??

```
  Id        EmpId              CheckTime                                CheckType
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3           5             2013-01-03 09:00:15.000                         1 
  4           5             2013-01-03 11:00:00.000                         2 
  5           5             2013-01-03 11:30:00.000                         1 
  6           5             2013-01-03 13:00:00.000                         2 
  7           5             2013-01-03 13:30:00.000                         1 
  8           5             2013-01-03 16:00:00.000                         2 
  9           5             2013-01-03 16:30:00.000                         1 
 10           5             2013-01-03 18:00:00.000                         2
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I am not understanding what you want to add to checktime.

Comment: what do you mean by add time?

Comment: i want to get the sum of checktime with checktype=1... (09:00:15.000   +11:30:00.000 +13:30:00.000+16:30:00.000 )

Comment: If you are looking for total time an employee worked, you shoud be doing this (11:00:00.000-09:00:15.000)+(13:00:00.000-11:30:00.000).. so on and so forth.

Comment: i am looking for that... but an employee can checkin and checkout more than once... so i want to sum up all time intervals...

Comment: Is `CheckType` of '1' equivalent to clocking in and '2' to clocking out??

Comment: do you want to total time of CheckType=1 and total time of CheckType=2

Comment: @Nicarus.. yes ,checktype = 1 means check in and checktype = 2 means check out   @ Prashant kathesia... yes and i want to find the difference of the two results

Comment: @user1498037 - Did you review my answer below to see if that works for you? It should...

Comment: Can you edit your question and also show your *expected* results, given your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do, if I understand you question correctly:

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    CheckTime,
    CheckType,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId, DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,cin.CheckTime),0), CheckType ORDER BY CheckTime) AS Seq
INTO
    #PreparedTable
FROM
    SourceTable


SELECT
    cin.EmpId,
    DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,cin.CheckTime),0) AS CheckDate,
    (SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,cin.CheckTime,cout.CheckTime)) / 3600.0) AS HoursWorked
FROM
    #PreparedTable cin
JOIN
    #PreparedTable cout
    ON  (cin.EmpId = cout.EmpID)
    AND (DATEDIFF(dd,cin.CheckTime,cout.CheckTime) = 0)
    AND (cin.Seq = cout.Seq)
    AND (cin.CheckType = 1)
    AND (cout.CheckType = 2)
```